# Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I want to make a python program that gets all links for a certain Google search query so I loop over the 30 search pages and when it gives me a ReCaptcha I do it manually 
here is how my code looks like :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
number_pages = 30
query = 'hello world'
query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query+"&&start="

with open('result.txt','w') as fp:
    for i in range(1,number_pages-1):
        # loop over the 30 pages
        page_url = url + str((i-1)*10)
        print("# " + page_url)


        driver.get(page_url)

        while len(driver.find_elements_by_id('recaptcha')) != 0:
            # ReCaptcha , sleeping until the user solve the recaptcha

            print('sleeping...!')
            time.sleep(10)

        els = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('cite')
```

But when i try to send the recaptcha form it gaves me the error:

```
Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again
```

and when I use a normal navigator (Google Chrome or Firefox ) the error don't occur
I think  the ReCaptcha blocks the webdriver

Please anyone can explain what exact issue here, and how can be fixed.

Comment: The whole point of a CAPTCHA is to prevent the kind of thing you're doing (software pretending to be a human). I don't think this is going to be easy to bypass, and looping through 30 pages of results is probably against their terms of use.

Comment: but I don't want to bypass the Recaptcha i want to solve it manually

Comment: That's what I mean. It's only supposed to work for real people. When software tries to solve it it's supposed to fail.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What's your actual goal? What do you want to do with the list of URLs you're trying to build?